# CSS animation only loops 3 times then stops

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a plane that I want to fly back and fourth infinitely. I have a Javascript listener for `animationend` that works just fine (I think.) It flies right, left, right, and then stops and resets at it's original position. When the listener fires, I just have it switch classes that are linked to the animations I want.

Here's the Javascript:

```
var runway = document.getElementById("myNavbar");

var plane = document.createElement('div');
plane.id = "plane";
plane.className = "plane-right";

runway.appendChild(plane);

$("#plane").one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
    if (plane.className == "plane-right")
    {
        plane.className = "plane-left";
    }
    else
    {
        plane.className = "plane-right";
    }
});
```

I also understand there's a jQuery `toggle()` function but I can't get it to work. I tried `$("#plane").toggle(".plane-right, .plane-left")` inside the listener but that didn't do the trick.

And the CSS class

```
.plane-right {
    background-image: url("../img/zoomzoom.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    animation-name: moveLeftToRight;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    position: relative;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.plane-left {
    background-image: url("../img/zoomzoom.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    position: relative;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  from   { left: -20%; }
  to { left: 110%; }
}
@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
  from   { left: 110%; }
  to { left: -20%; }
}
```

Update: I added an `alert()` to the listener, and the alert does not fire the last time the animation ends before the plane resets position. Not sure if this is significant or helpful, but there it is.

Comment: Also, I'd like to note that when the plane stops it does stop with the `plane-right` class, so it IS applying the class, but not the animation.

Comment: toggle hides or shows the element. Is that what you want? It can take a boolean value.

Comment: That makes sense. No I want it switch between the two classes every time the animation ends

Comment: $("#plane").toggleClass('plane-right plane-left'), but I think it may only work one direction

Comment: actually, that should do it. It will remove each class in the list if it exists, or add it if it doesn't. However...that may not be your problem.

Comment: That's what I thought toggle() did, and it did work, but only as much as my if statements did. (It stops after 3 cycles)

Comment: that's what I expected. Post your css of animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "on" instead of "one".  Using "one" only triggers once, although in this case twice and I'm not 100% sure why. It may be multiple event types (webkitanimationend AND animationend), but I'd think those would happen one after another.

https://jsfiddle.net/ftgr6h1e/

```
$("#plane").on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
```

Now, in general, animating position is slow. Consider animating transform3D instead to use the GPU to redraw your plane.